# Anova function does not work on mblogit models?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, anova, mixed-models, multinomial

I am running a multinomial model with hunting season as mixed effect using the `mblogit` function. The model runs perfectly but I cannot run the `Anova` function (`car` package) to get an analyses of deviance table. I get the following error:

> Error in SS[n.terms + 1] <- if (missing(error)) sumry$sigma^2 * mod$df.residual else error.SS :
> replacement has length zero

My code is the following

```
library(mclogit)
modeldata$Hunting_season <- modeldata$`Hunting season`
modeldata$Age_class <- modeldata$`Age class`
model_mult <- mblogit( formula = Age_class ~ Group*Sex + Period,  
              random = ~ 1|Hunting_season , 
              data = modeldata)
summary(model_mult)
Anova(model_mult)
```

Any suggestions on what may cause the error, or which alternative function I could use?

Answer (score 0):

It's not super-easy to get immediate gratification (an `Anova()` function that automatically gives you a hypothesis test for the effect of each predictor variable in the model).

```r
library(mclogit)
library(car)  ## for Anova
data("housing", package = "MASS")
house.mblogit <- mblogit(Sat ~ Infl*Type + Cont, weights = Freq,
                              data = housing)
```

You can try `methods("Anova")` to see what kinds of models (objects) `car::Anova()` can fit (unfortunately, not `mblogit` or `mclogit` objects). You can also try

```r
lapply(class(house.mblogit), function(c) methods(class = c))
```

to see what methods are available for the model you've fitted (although the last set of entries, which are for class `lm`, are probably not really relevant ...)

There is an `anova()` method, but it only works to compare nested sets of already fitted models — not to decompose an individual model.

You can do this by hand, though, by fitting nested models (either by adding/subtracting terms on the right-hand side of the formula or by replacing the RHS). The bad news is that you can only compare **nested sequences of models** this way, and draw conclusions about the significance of terms included/excluded from pairs in that sequence.

Here is one example:

```r
## infl, type, and interaction (drop cont)
m_infltype <- update(house.mblogit, . ~ . - Cont)
## additive effects of infl and type (and cont), no interaction
m_infltypeadd <- update(house.mblogit, . ~ . - Infl*Type + Infl + Type)
m_infl <- update(house.mblogit, . ~ . - Infl*Type + Infl)
m_type <- update(house.mblogit, . ~ . - Infl*Type + Type)
## Cont only
m_cont <- update(house.mblogit, . ~ Cont)
m_null <- update(house.mblogit, . ~ 1)
```

```r
anova(house.mblogit, m_infltypeadd, m_infl, m_cont, m_null,
       test = "Chisq")
```

The difficulty of computing significance for a term in a complex model is that (outside of linear models in balanced experimental designs) the significance depends on the order in which you evaluate the terms. `car::Anova()` has fancier ways of doing this (its 'type 2' Anova evaluates a focal term with all other terms included in the model, except for higher-order interactions involving the term; its 'type 3' is different - see the 'Details' and 'Warning' sections in `?car::Anova`).

An alternative would be to compute an AIC table, e.g. with `MuMIn::dredge`

```r
h2 <- update(house.mblogit, na.action = na.fail) ## required for dredge()
MuMIn::dredge(h2)
```

Comment: Hi,                                                                                                                                           Thanks for answering, I tried the AIC table using the MuMIn package, but unlike when I try it with your data, It doesn't add the AIC values to the table. What could cause this?  It states: Models ranked by AICc(x)... But I only see a ranking of the models and variables included.